# Managing files copy/paste within Qt pro-file

Tags: qt, profile

In my Qt project i have some files that should be located in drectory located against with executable(it should be in filesystem, I cannot place it into resources).
The question is: can I manage these files to be copied into correct location on app build within .pro file? What is the best approach for managing stuff like that?
inb4: I could use QMAKE_POST_LINK to run shell scripts to manage this. This is no good solution, since I have to build my app both for linux and windows.

Comment: You should write an installer for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QMake really does have a features that you can use to copy files when application is builded. Unfortunatedly information how it is use seems to be quite hard to find.

While digging I actually found this one:
[Other Topic on issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984104/qmake-how-to-copy-a-file-to-the-output)

So ripped example from there:

```
images.path    = $${DESTDIR}/images
images.files   += images/splashscreen.png
images.files   += images/logo.png
INSTALLS       += images
```

This should also work in all OS's directly.