# QtCreator - how to set in the *.pro file to move few other files

Tags: qt-creator, qmake

I want to have quite portable project with the QtCreator. I may edit only the *.pro file. The *.pro.user should be left untouched. The environment compile by default to a new directory. Unfortunately I have few other files to copy there too. What have I to write in the *.pro file to accomplish it? Is there something quite simple?

If I write my own Makefile (or something), I'll lost integration with the QtCreator. It's not an option.

**EDIT**:
It is somehow duplicate of this question:
[QMake - how to copy a file to the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984104/qmake-how-to-copy-a-file-to-the-output)

However I would prefer to not write custom scripts inside the *.pro file. I would prefer to not use platform specific conditions too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [QMake - how to copy a file to the output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984104/qmake-how-to-copy-a-file-to-the-output)

Answer (score -1):

Check out the [INSTALLS variable for QMake](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qmake-environment-reference.html#installs).  The only drawback is that it will require you to run `make install` after a `make`.