# QT: specify project directories like "build" and "src" in ".pro" flie

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator, qmake

I have a project hierarchy like this:

```
file.pro

src/
    files.cpp

include/
    headers.h

build/
    files.o

bin/
    finalExecutable
```

What to specify in the `.pro` file so that the Makefile generated by `qmake` takes the `.cpp` files from my `src/` directory and put the executable in the `build` directory?

For the `include` part, I have added `INCLUDEPATH += include/*`, and it seems to work other than the fact that while including any `file.h` I have to write `#include <include/file.h>` instead of `#include <file.h>`. 
How to put it in the `.pro` file so that I can include headers like `#include <file.h>`.

I tried to add `SOURCES += src/*`, but it shows an error:

```
error: No rule to make target 'sourceFiles/*', needed by 'mydialog.o'.  Stop.
```

How to go about specifying the `include`, `src` and the `build` directories?

Answer (score 2):

This should be easy. Just include this in your `.pro` file

```
MOC_DIR     = ./build/moc
OBJECTS_DIR = ./build/obj
RCC_DIR     = ./build/qrc
UI_DIR      = ./build/uic
```

and voilà, the folder `build` and its subdirectories are created as soon as you execute qmake.

Also when you have local includes, you should not use `#include <localheader.h>` it should be `#include "localheader.h"`

Comment: The Build part worked perfectly fine. As for the include in my custom Makefile if I pass the flags `-I include/` then `g++` automatically takes in the headers from `include/` and I am able to write `#include <file.h>`. It's very difficult and not so nice to include the absolute path in `""` with all the `../../` and other things. So how to do the same thing with a `.pro` file

Comment: also how to specify the `src` directory?

Comment: The code now accepts the `src/` after adding the build lines.

Comment: I did not notice its not `INCLUDEPATH += include/*` it should be `INCLUDEPATH += include/`. I believe that will fix your issue. Also when you set the `INCLUDEPATH` you'll not have to use `#include "../../file.h"`, you can just give `#include "file.h"` It will work.

Answer (score 1):

Qmake files that specify build directories as source subdirectories, and that assume that qmake is executed in the source folder, are essentially broken. The recommended way to build any project (even non-Qt projects!) is to do it out of source. I.e.:

```
# suppose the sources are in myproject
mkdir myproject-build
cd myproject-build
qmake ../myproject && make      # for qmake projects
cmake ../myproject && make      # for cmake projects
../myproject/configure && make  # for autotools projects
```

The sensible thing to do, of course, is to hardlink (or copy) all the executables into some common subfolder of the build directory. This requires some more gymnastics. E.g.:

```
EXTRA_BINFILES += $$PWD/src/myproject # target name in src.pro
DESTDIR = $$OUT_PWD/bin
QMAKE_PRE_LINK += $$QMAKE_MKDIR_CMD $$DIR
for(FILE, EXTRA_BINFILES){
  QMAKE_POST_LINK += \
    $$QMAKE_COPY $$shell_path($$FILE) $$shell_path($$DIR) $$escape_expand(\\n\\t)
}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984104/qmake-how-to-copy-a-file-to-the-output) for more insight.