# QMake: copy files and folder from source directory to build directory

Tags: qt, qmake

This is my first time using QMake on my QT as I mostly use CMake as I am really used to it. In Cmake I use add_custom_command() to perform task post build.

How can I do similar things in qmake?
My initial check I know it is something related to QMAKE_POST_LINK
but how do I specify it is for the build directory? (which as setup/created by QT Creator during build)

also by basic googling, i only found for unix{} and win32{} whats for mac?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QMake - how to copy a file to the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984104/qmake-how-to-copy-a-file-to-the-output)

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion, but ive tried it and it does not work if im planning to copy a folder to DESTDIR. when i tried making it like DESTDIR\target folder, it does not work,
Any suggestion on how to transfer an entire folder to build directory?

So I have a "resource" folder in my source directory and i want to copy it to my build directory as a resource for exe to use during run (when application is run from QT creator)

So basically my question is, how to copy folder to build directory?

Comment: Did you try `$$QMAKE_COPY_DIR`?

Comment: no sorry didnt know that, as i said im new to qmake, thanks!

Comment: 'Tis all sounds as a misuse. If you need to install some stuff then go with `INSTALLS`. `DESTDIR` is pretty much useless.